# Image Animation not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I want to animated image after 0.7 sec but they not working they do not show image on my View.

```
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L1.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L2.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L3.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L4.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L5.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L6.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L7.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L8.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L9.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L10.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L11.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L12.png"]];
self.imagsd.animationImages=images;
self.imagsd.animationDuration=0.7;
```

Comment: Have you verified that `self.imagsd` is not `nil` and that it has a proper frame?

Comment: yes it is on my view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `startAnimating` on your image view.

Comment: `[self.imagsd startAnimating];`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Load images



 NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L1.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L2.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L3.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L4.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L5.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L6.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L7.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L8.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L9.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L10.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L11.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L12.png"]];

// Normal Animation
UIImageView *animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 95, 86, 193)];
animationImageView.animationImages = images;
animationImageView.animationDuration = 0.5;

[self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
[animationImageView startAnimating];
```